# Creating Plug-In for Eclipse and utilizing external JAR-File

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, import, jar

I am trying to write a plug-in or Eclipse, that creates a view with a couple of buttons which I want to trigger methods in JAR-Files.

I have tried for days now and I read a lot about the topic on the net, but so far nothing worked for me.

No matter, what I do, I always come up with a Class Definition not found error.

Can anybody please explain the steps I have to take to make for example a little Plugin (using the view example) that calls an external JAR with one Method to write "Hello World" to the console?

Why is this so hard to get to work. Do I miss anything here? Is there maybe a good tutorial I didn't find.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Plugins generally don't use external jars. Any code you want to use should be in the plugin (or another plugin). You can include extra jars in a plugin - is that what you want to do?

Comment: I want to export a JAR which I then want to include (import) in my Plug-In project

Comment: If  you mean the jar will not be available when the plugin is loaded you will have to use `URLClassLoader` to load the jar dynamically